# How to animate TranslateTransform and ScaleTransform in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, doubleanimation

I'm trying to animate the `TranslateTransform` and `ScaleTransform` of a `Rectangle` at the same time using a `StoryBoard` in code-behind. I studied some similar questions but I some how I'm still stuck at the first step.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Aqua"></Rectangle>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Animate" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"/>
</Grid>

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var translate_x = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 100,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };
        var translate_y = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 0,
            To = 100,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };

        var scale_x = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 1,
            To = 2,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };

        var scale_y = new DoubleAnimation()
        {
            From = 1,
            To = 2,
            Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XAML, give your rectangle a TransformGroup:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="MyRectangle" Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Chartreuse">
    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="rectScale"/>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="rectTrans"/>
        </TransformGroup>
   </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
</Rectangle>
```

In the code-behind, use the BeginAnimation method on the transforms:

```
rectScale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, scale_x);
rectScale.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, scale_y);
rectTrans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, translate_x);
rectTrans.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, translate_y);
```

Comment: And I don't need storyboards?

Comment: If you want to start the animations all at the same time, you don't need storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

If `rectScale.BeginAnimation()` doesn't work try
`rectScale.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, scale_x);`